# Optional join in Diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I want to add conditional filter on joined table:

```rust
let query = first_table::table.into_boxed();

if Some(filter_string) = filter {
  // ERROR: inner_join() generates value of new type,
  // cannot assign it to boxed query
  query = query
    .inner_join(joined_table::table.on(...))
    .filter(jointed_table::dsl::string_field.eq(filter_string))
}

// joined_table actually is not required here
let result = query.select(first_table::all_columns).load(...)?;
```

Is there a way to downcast type of modified query into original one's, or may be there's another way to do that without copy-pasting final chain .select().load() into condition?

Comment: This is nothing diesel supports out of the box, as it cannot check queries without knowing the `FROM` clause at compile time.